# how to downgrade fullcalendar version 3.1.0 to 3.0.1 using npm

Tags: angular, fullcalendar-scheduler

how to downgrade fullCalendar version from 3.1.0 to 3.0.1 is there any command ? i am looking for change in the  node_modules/primeng/schedule/schedule.js file. i want to revert this file to older version. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`npm install fullcalendar@3.0.1`